# How to change UIView height based on elements inside it

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uitextview

I am creating a chat interface and have a UITextview and button for sending message inside a UIView. The height of UITextView changes based on its content size but UIView height does not change with it. [Chat view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7nwO.png)

I will appreciate any help on this.

Here are constraints on the message field [Message field constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ7oL.png)

Comment: Try using the sizeToFit() method, or use four constraints to anchor the edges of the internal views to the edges of the superview and use the internal views to dictate the sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set autolayout constraints specifying a fixed space and pin them from your `UIView` top to the `UITextView` top and from your UIView bottom to the UITextView bottom.

It is unclear from your question how you are setting the height of your container view and your text view. You should have a height constraint on the text view and change its constant when you want to resize the text view. Do not change the frame directly. The container view must not have a height constraint - it should resize solely because of the bottom and top constraints to the text view.

Comment: Then you should show us how you tried this. Because, if you are using autolayout (as you should), this _is_ the way you would normally do it.

Comment: I have edited my answer. If it still doesn't solve your problem then tell us of any other constraints and how you are setting the height. Also if you are setting the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property.

Answer (score 6):

**If you programmatically created the view:**

```
containerView.frame.size.height = textView.frame.size.height
```

**If you create the view in the storyboard**

Create a height constraint for your view. Then connect that constraint to your code. Then run this:

```
heightConstraint.constant = textView.frame.size.height
```

Comment: I am using aspect ratio constraint on my UIView so I am not able to use height constraint on it.

Answer (score 1):

without auto layout code:

```
txtView.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x + 8, view.frame.origin.y + 8, view.frame.size.width - 100, view.frame.size.height - 16);

btnSend.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width - 92, (view.frame.size.height/2) - 25, 84, 50);
```